# How to use the go API provided by geth to call smart contracts?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

```
    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:        &contractAddr,
        Gas:       uint64(21000),
        GasTipCap: tipCap,
        GasFeeCap: feeCap,
        Data:
    }
    client.CallContract(context.Background(), msg, nil)
```

I want to use this API to call smart contracts, but I don't know what to fill in the "Data" field. Can someone provide an example for my reference? Thans very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [ethereum.CallMsg](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#CallMsg) is struct this

```
type CallMsg struct {
    From      common.Address  // the sender of the 'transaction'
    To        *common.Address // the destination contract (nil for contract creation)
    Gas       uint64          // if 0, the call executes with near-infinite gas
    GasPrice  *big.Int        // wei <-> gas exchange ratio
    GasFeeCap *big.Int        // EIP-1559 fee cap per gas.
    GasTipCap *big.Int        // EIP-1559 tip per gas.
    Value     *big.Int        // amount of wei sent along with the call
    Data      []byte          // input data, usually an ABI-encoded contract method invocation

    AccessList types.AccessList // EIP-2930 access list.
}
```

and here Data have a type of `[]byte`

> but I don't know what to fill in the "Data" field

in the Data field, you need to provide ABI-encoded contract method invocation

To create ABI-encoded contract method you need to import
`"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"` and use [abi.Pack](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi#ABI.Pack) method

for your reference, you can look at test cases [abi_test.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.10.21/accounts/abi/abi_test.go)